# perl prevent key value duplicates

Tags: perl

I'm looping through a file line by line, it has key->value pair that I'm then outputting to xml. How can I do a check to make sure I haven't already outputted this key/value pair?
In C# I would do it so easy by inserting into dictionary then just using .Contains(), any tips in perl?

Comment: The answers are good.  You could also consider just using 'uniq' on the input file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has the [`defined`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#defined) and [`exists`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#exists) keywords that operate on hash elements.

```
$hash{'foo'} = 'bar';
print defined $hash{'foo'};      #  prints 1
print exists $hash{'foo'};       #  prints 1
```

For most purposes, they do the same thing. The one subtle difference is when the hash value is the special "undefined" value:

```
$hash{'baz'} = undef;
print defined $hash{'baz'};      # doesn't print 1
print exists $hash{'baz'};       # prints 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing using a perl hash.

```
my %seen;
while (my $line = <$filehandle>)
{
  next if ($seen{$line});
  print $line;
  $seen{$line} = 1;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to change that `next if ($seen{$line});` to `next if (exists $seen{$line});`, otherwise logically false values like a blank string or the string "0" will never be printed.

Comment: @Consp The conditional is testing whether the value *associated with* `$line` is true, and the values in `%seen` will all be strictly `undef` or 1. That said, the loop body could be condensed to a more compact and idiomatic `print $line unless $seen{$line}++;`.

Comment: My bad.  Somehow I only read two of the three lines of the loop, and had presumed you were populating the hash with string content.  i.e. The key/value store.